# Suggested edit completely changed during review

Tags: support, reviews, suggested-edits

I just did a review on a suggested edit.

After reviewing, I headed to my profile and opend the [review link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16922) from there, to see how the review went on. I am puzzeled and confused now, because the edit that is displayed there is completely different to what I have been reviewing.

The suggested edit that I had a look at had the following changes:

- Changing *"Utopia"* to *"Eutopia"* in the title and link description
- Adding the *"(from his "Republic")"* to the title

I rejected the edit, because after a quick google search and a look at the link in the question, I found no occurences of *"Eutopia"* in this context, the original source only mentioned *"Utopia"* as well. Further, a third *"Utopia*" in the content was completely left untouched.

How is this possible? Up to now I was sure that you cannot change an edit once it is suggested. Am I going mad? There have been no conflicting edits or anything, I would [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), but I cannot see where it could be an issure here.

Comment: That's an interesting question, when I reviewed that edit, the only change was the plot -> Plato in the title. If what you point out in the answer is correct then it might be a bug in the review process. One could make a simple edit, get approved, and then re-edit and write anything in.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin That't what I was thinking as well. However, it might be the edit gets fixd once approved, so there would always be at least one reviewer to see the final suggestion. However, this is only a guess and would still be a problem.

Comment: yeah, but that still defeats the concept of having two reviewers...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Absolutely! Thats what I meant with "there would still be a problem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the reason:

The five minute grace period seems to be [applied to suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276542/edits-suggested-within-a-grace-period-shouldnt-appear-as-part-of-the-original-e) as well, meaning that a second edit suggestion within five minutes after the first would be merged into the original suggestion.

It seems like there is no notification for reviewers.